# Appledoc - grouping classes by categories

Tags: appledoc

I'm using Appledoc for generate comments. 
In basic variants i get page like this http://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/

I want to get something like this http://qblx.co/OrAHzE - classes grouped by categories.

I read this doc http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc-docs-comments/ , by not found any information about this. Anybody did something like this? tanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered on email, this is not currently supported.

From perspective of the author of appledoc: one of the goals of appledoc was to generate documentation looking as close to Apple's own as possible. As Apple doesn't use "sections" on index pages, such functionality wasn't implemented on appledoc as well and also isn't planned.